# How can i connect open cv file (for playing video) when i click push button in an UI file?

Tags: python, qt-designer, video-player

I tried importing cv2. But When I import it in my python file with ui, it overwrite the code, and it is the first one to run, which supposedly, it should be the other python file. It should just be run when only i click the push button. Kindly help me. :< Beginner here.

Or do you have other ideas on how to play external video like mp4 which is also saved in the same folder.

I'm using qtdesigner, python.

Comment: You can reach out to me! It's highly appreciated! ♥

Comment: what do you exactly import? How it can `overwrite the code` ? Maybe you should put code in functions so after importing you can decide when to run functions.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIvCCs8b3Rk -- i used this code to display videos when I click the button i created in other window. Do you have any idea sir what kind of function should i call? I badly needed help for someone who knows much better than me.

Comment: As I expected - first you have to put your code with `opencv` in some function `def my_function(): ....` in your `my_file.py` and when you import it `import my_file` then it will not run it automatically but you have to use `my_file.my_function()` to run it. So you may assign it to button to run it.

Comment: I have tried it but still got some errors. Or i did a wrong one? Haha sorry sir. I'm still learning this language

Comment: so first you have to learn: we can't read in your mind - you have to show all detalis in question. Without details we have no clue and we can't help you. Besides we will not write all code from scratch for you.

Comment: BTW: you could see other questions to see what other people put in question to get answer.

Comment: noted with that sir! thank you very much!

Comment: at this moment I can only suggest post like [Displaying Opencv images in PyQT – Image Tracking](https://www.imagetracking.org.uk/2020/12/displaying-opencv-images-in-pyqt/). As you can see all code is in classes and functions - and this can be your problem. You don't keep code in functions - so you can't control when it is executed and it is executed directly when you import file. You don't have to keep code in classes but you should keep in functions.

Comment: thank you for your advice sir. So much appreciated. :)